# How to handle array passed into HTML from a Flask app?

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a Flask app code to get images from S3 and store them in an array and render a template called *default_screen_html*

```
@app.route('/tch/default_screen', methods=['GET'])
def get_default_screen():
  image_url = []

  for bucket in s3_resource.buckets.all():
      for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='Prefix1/Prefix2/'):
          params = {'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': obj.key}
          image_url.append(s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', params))

  return render_template('default_screen.html', images=image_url)
```

But in my *default_screen.html* file the code can't quite read the url from the array

```
<div  class="uk-position-relative uk-visible-toggle uk-light" uk-slideshow="autoplay: true;autoplay-interval: 6000; animation: pull;">
        <ul uk-height-viewport="offset-top: true" class="uk-slideshow-items">
            {% for image in images %} 
                <li>
                    <img src="{{images}}" alt="" uk-cover>
                </li> 
            {% endfor %} 
        </ul>
    
    </div>
```

Any help would be strongly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing `images` instead of `image` on your `for loop`.

Change your loop to

```html
{% for image in images %}
    <li>
        <img src="{{image}}" alt="" uk-cover>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```